# How to encrypt data with multi public keys using openssl library

Tags: openssl

I have two public keys and I use below command to encrypt the data with these two public keys

openssl smime -encrypt -binary -aes256 -in secret.txt -out secret_multi.enc -outform PEM alice.pub bob.pub

so basically with alice.pub and bob.pub  I can able to decrypt  the data secret_multi.enc with thier private keys.

Please help me how I can achieve this using openssl API functions.

That is encrypt the data with multiple keys.

Equivalent to the command I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The openssl smime -encrypt command uses the [PKCS7_encrypt](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PKCS7_encrypt.html) API to encrypt the data with the stack of certificates.

Here is a example of using it that reproduces the above command using C++ usage of the C API.

```
template<typename T, typename D>
std::unique_ptr<T, D> make_handle(T* handle, D deleter)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T, D>{handle, deleter};
}

bool encrypt_data()
{
    // load the stack of certificates
    auto const encrypt_certificate_stack = make_handle(sk_X509_new_null(), [](auto handle){ sk_X509_pop_free(handle, X509_free); });
    if(!encrypt_certificate_stack) return false;

    auto file = make_handle(BIO_new_file("alice.pem", "r"), BIO_free);
    auto cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(file.get(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if(!cert) return false;
    sk_X509_push(encrypt_certificate_stack.get(), cert);

    file = make_handle(BIO_new_file("bob.pem", "r"), BIO_free);
    cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(file.get(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
    if(!cert) return false;
    sk_X509_push(encrypt_certificate_stack.get(), cert);

    // input file
    auto const infile = make_handle(BIO_new_file("secret.txt", "rb"), BIO_free);
    if(!infile) return false;

    // encrypt
    auto const flags = PKCS7_DETACHED | PKCS7_BINARY;
    auto const p7 = make_handle(PKCS7_encrypt(encrypt_certificate_stack.get(), infile.get(), EVP_aes_256_cbc(), flags), PKCS7_free);
    if(!p7) return false;

    // write the output file as PEM format
    auto const outfile = make_handle(BIO_new_file("secret.out.pem", "w"), BIO_free);
    if(!outfile) return false;
    if(PEM_write_bio_PKCS7_stream(outfile.get(), p7.get(), infile.get(), flags) == 0) return false;

    return true;
}
```

UPDATE:

The [PKCS7_decrypt](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PKCS7_decrypt.html) API states:

> Although the recipients certificate is not needed to decrypt the data
>   it is needed to locate the appropriate (of possible several)
>   recipients in the PKCS#7 structure.

Meaning that the certificate is *optional* so you can pass in a nullptr to that argument and it will work ok in your simple example.

If you do pass in the certificate, it will match the certificate to the private key and if that fails the decrypt will fail.

So the decrypt code without a certficate would look like:

```
bool decrypt_data()
{
    // read in private key
    auto file = make_handle(BIO_new_file("aliceprivatekey.pem", "r"), BIO_free);
    auto const key = make_handle(PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(file.get(), nullptr, nullptr, (void*)"password"), EVP_PKEY_free);
    file.reset();
    if(!key) return false;

    // read in PKCS7 data
    auto infile = make_handle(BIO_new_file("secret.out.pem", "rb"), BIO_free);
    if(!infile) return false;

    auto const p7 = make_handle(PEM_read_bio_PKCS7(infile.get(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr), PKCS7_free);
    if (!p7) return false;
    infile.reset();

    // decrypt and write to stdout
    auto const out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    auto const flags = PKCS7_DETACHED;
    return PKCS7_decrypt(p7.get(), key.get(), nullptr, out, flags) != 0;
}
```

UPDATE 2:

There is a [memory BIO](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/BIO_s_mem.html) that can be used for memory only BIO if you want to use in memory buffers only with the openssl API.

```
std::vector<char> data;
auto memory_bio = make_handle(BIO_new_mem_buf(data.data(), data.size()), BIO_free);
```

Comment: Thanks.
Also I want to how can I decrypt the data by using only private key?
I see the API for decryption needs both private key and public key(cert) but I need to decrypt only using private key is that possible?

int PKCS7_decrypt(PKCS7 *p7, EVP_PKEY *pkey, X509 *cert, BIO *data, int flags);

Comment: Thanks.
Also I want to how can I decrypt the data by using only private key?
I see the API for decryption needs both private key and public key(cert) but I need to decrypt only using private key is that possible?

int PKCS7_decrypt(PKCS7 *p7, EVP_PKEY *pkey, X509 *cert, BIO *data, int flags);

openssl smime -decrypt -in secret_single.enc -inform PEM -inkey alice.key

above command I need to execute but without public key

Comment: these all examples work well with file options
suppose if I have a data of stream like vector<unsigned char> plaintext
so do I need to create a file first with this data to get the BIO*
or there is any direct method to get the BIO * from  vector<unsigned char> plaintext ?

Comment: Added memory bio example.

Comment: is there any way to read the data from BIO.
I saw BIOS_read() but it needs the buffer length to be copied but how would I know that how my bytes I needs to copy since the data will be in BIO structure

Comment: I assume you mean BIO_read, that is the only way.  Not sure what you mean by "BIO structure".  You can think of it like a fread like call.  You just need to call it in a loop until it's all the data "read"  out.  If it's a memory bio (BIO_s_mem) you can get the pointer out using BIO_get_mem_data and then you can "copy" from it directly if required.